# How do I unit test a JobSchduler in android

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-jobscheduler

I have written code to run tasks on job scheduler. Testing it on real device works fine. But i wanted a way to unit test it so that i can be sure it is covering all conditions like job success/failure/ runs when conditions are met, periodic etc. Please suggest me a way to write unit tests for these scenarios

Comment: Test the logic, not the service

Answer (score 0):

You can run jobs on-demand via adb, as well as force an immediate timeout of an executing job as though it had reached the end of its timeslice.  See the output of

```
adb shell cmd jobscheduler
```

for a summary of useful commands.